# New Skype (v8.x) setup forces installing Skype from Windows Store

Tags: skype, compatibility, windows-10-v1709

I have just attempted to install Skype v8.12.0.2 on one of my network user's laptops (running Windows 10 Enterprise x64 build 1709) using the standalone/offline installer.

Running as admin, the installer loads then brings up message box stating "Please install skype from the windows store for the best experience" and given no option to continue with the offline install.

Is there a parameter I can use when running the installer to stop it doing this?

(FYI - The laptop is unable to access the Windows Store due to network restrictions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Reason:**

According to [Skype System Requirements](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/fa10328/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-skype):

> New Skype on Windows desktop requires:
>
> ***Windows 10 Version 1507, or version 1511***
>
> Windows 8.1
>
> Windows 8
>
> Windows 7 (32-bit and 64 bit versions supported)

Meaning it's not compatible with Windows 10 Anniversary Update (Version 1607) or higher. (Technically, it is! But Microsoft prefers, or in other words, wants to force you to use Windows Store!)

**Solution:**

Setting compatibility mode to Windows 7/8 does not work for everyone. From an elevated command line window navigate to the folder containing [New Skype (v8.x)](https://go.skype.com/windows.desktop.download) setup file and then run it with **"/Silent"** switch (case insensitive):

```
pushd C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\Programs
C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\Programs>Skype-8.12.0.2.exe /silent
```

Comment: Current download link is here :  https://go.skype.com/windows.desktop.download  .   If using Chrome or Edge on windows 10, the download page on skype.com's windows link, is for the Microsoft Store. Posting this link here as I am unsure how long it will be visible in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

I don't often answer my own questions but have just come across a fix for this:

> Run the installer in "Compatibility mode" (Windows 8) and it installs fine.

Quite why the most recent version of Skype wont install directly on the most recent build of Windows is anyone's guess, but that's the work-around.

Comment: Because, at least in my experience, the Windows Store version of Skype really is better. I do regular 3-5 participant conference calls and the old app used to crash every second or third call, while the new one has never crashed for me.

Comment: Its not old though, its the current build. I wouldnt mind if it even gave the option to "Continue anyway" . 

I havent used skype myself since microsoft bought it, and destroyed MSN messenger at the same time,

Comment: "Old" doesn't mean age, it means the "old fashioned" regular app.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the exe with the `/?` switch, it will provide the numerous switches available to this installer

[image]

Notable for this issue are the following:

```
C:\~\Skype-8.18.0.6.exe /verysilent /norestart
```

This suppresses the installation (/silent still has an interface popup), and prevents restart. Unfortunately, I'm not able to figure out how to prevent it from launching still.